# How to update while not upsert a sub field in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have docs like

`{"_id":100, "age": {"bob": 20, "jack": 30}}`

and I only want to update existing person with their ages,but if I update a non-existent user:

`db.products.update({ _id: 100 }, {$set: { "age.tom": 10 }})`,

mongo will create "tom" and set the age which is not my expectation.

Related doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

> If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field, $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the dotted path to the field.

Any way to do the update while not `upsert` for a sub-field?

Comment: Can you show us how you are doing the update?

Comment: @chridam db.example.update({ _id: 100 },{ $set: { "age.tom": 10 }})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.example.update({ "age.tom":{$exists:true} },{ $set: { "age.tom": 10 }})
```

if you want `"_id"` as a filter then ,

```
db.example.update({"_id" : 100, "age.tom":{$exists:true} },{ $set: { "age.tom": 10 }})
```